# Not able to get how Messagebox works with strings

Tags: .net, vb.net, compiler-errors

I am using a vb.net function which has the following signature

```
 Public Function I18N(ByVal strId As String, ByVal strEnglishDescr As String) As String
```

So during function calling 1st parameter shall be a string .

But i am confused how the below call is working . since here i pass 9 and 10 , instead of CStr(9) and CStr(10)

```
MsgBox(I18N(9, "E2 Data was corrupt.  Using ") & "MyName" & I18N(10, " data."))
```

i am directly calling

`Me.Text = I18N(9, "Data was corrupt.  Using ")`

```
 this is too not giving the compiler error .
```

Is it internally converting integer to string ?

Please help me in it . I am new to coding .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Please include the compiler error.

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to replicate. With Option Strict On, integers cannot be written in any case. With Option Strict Off, the can be used in both cases.

Comment: sorry . i posted the 2nd one having as compiler error . But actually its working fine . My question is like whether its internally converting integer to string ?

I have edited my question .

Comment: Is it converting to String? Yes. This is what VB.NET does when Option Strict On is not written at the top of your file (performing automatic castings to the target formats); as far as doing that is not recommendable (ideally, you should always cast to the right type yourself), it is advisable to write always Option Strict On at the top, what avoids this kind of situations and forces you to make the casting. Nothing to do with MsgBox.

Comment: ya i got it . But even if i make option strict on, its working fine .

Comment: If you write Option Strict On at the top of the file, VS wouldn't allow you to compile this code without casting both numbers to string.

Comment: But its allowing . Thats what i mentioned in the above comment .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41990/discussion-between-jensar-and-varocarbas)

Answer (score -1):

The function parameters are defined as type string. You're passing an integer, which is not of type string. Therefore it's failing to compile.

If you're expected to pass integer ids then the function is declared wrong. Otherwise you should be figuring out what string to pass rather than integers.

Comment: The OP seems to be asking why what you say does not happen when writing it inside MsgBox()